# why temp and c can access a and b private variables using dot operator?

Tags: c++, function, object

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class complex
{
    int a,b;

    public:
    void set_data(int a,int b)
    {
        this->a=a;
        this->b=b;
    }
    void show_data()
    {
        cout<<a<<"+"<<b<<"i";
    }
    complex add(complex c)
    {
        complex temp;
        temp.a=a+c.a;
        temp.b=b+c.b;
        return temp;
    }
};
int main()
{
    complex c1,c2;
    c1.set_data(5,6);`
    c2.set_data(4,5);
    complex c3=c1.add(c2);
    c3.show_data();
}
```

here temp and c are accessing a and b by . operator

why temp and c can access a and b private variables using dot operator???

but private variables are not accessible outside of class.

Comment: `temp` is a `complex` itself and is therefore trusted.  It would be really hard to write C++ code if that wouldn't be the case.

Comment: The `private` and `protected` keywords work per _class_ and not per _instance_. Method `add` is a member of `complex`, and therefore has access to `private` members, even for other instances of `complex` than `this`.

Comment: but if i do the same thing in main function there will be no access to variables a and b!

Comment: `main` is not a `complex`  member function - it's a free function.

Comment: _"but private variables are not accessible outside of class."_ - where do you use `temp`? Inside `complex` or outside?

Comment: so the scope of private keyword is what???

Comment: It's for everything _not_ being a `complex`

Comment: i used temp inside class. inside the class made a new object of that class, and then I am able to access its member variables. but the scope of a and b is just available for member functions. so according to me they should haven't been able to be accessed by dot operator anywhere.

Comment: As prapin said, the scope of `private` is the class.   Specifically any member functions of the class or `friend`s of the class (which can only be declared within the class definition) can access `private` members of any instance of that class, or any `static` members that are also `private`.

Comment: so ted if i make a class and inside that I make member functions and in the member functions if I make any object of the same class then member variables are accessible using dot operator inside that function even if the variables are private??

Comment: The `add()` function is a member of `complex`.   It can therefore access `private` members of `temp` (which is an instance, of automatic storage duration, of `complex` created with the `add()` member function).     The `add()` member function can also access members of `c`, that is a `complex` passed to it by value.

Answer (score 4):

Taken from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access):

> A class defined with the keyword class has private access for its members and its base classes by default. A class defined with the keyword struct has public access for its members and its base classes by default. A union has public access for its members by default.

And

> A private member of a class is only accessible to the members and friends of that class, regardless of whether the members are on the same or different instances

Meaning that you can use `a` or `b` (by default `private` members of your `class complex`) **inside** the class, but every other class or function **outside** of the class can't have access to them. For that to happen you will need accessors (setters/getters) inside your class.

Those accessors come under the OOP rule of [Encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming))

ex.

```
int Get_a()
{
    return this->a;
}

void Set_a(int other)
{
    this->a = other;
}
```

Also, as already said in the comments, temp and c are themselves of type complex and have access to private members.

Comment: what is the friends of a class??

Comment: @AnshulPareek given that you are new to c++ there is no need to pay attention to a friend class. What matters to you now is that a class that has private members can only access them from inside the class. Every other function or class or instance of the same class can't access them.

Comment: but in my code temp is an object made of class complex, so why this have access to a and b??  and also inside the class only member functions can access private variables??

Comment: `temp` has access because `private`'s scope is the class and `temp` is declared and used inside the class. As for the second question, every member of the class can access private variables inside the class. Most of what I am answering is already answered in the comments above. Inside class `complex` you can use all `private` members even from instances of class `complex`. But only inside the class.